# newly uploaded images in vite4 and vue3 not show after build on production

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, vuejs3, vite

I have problems with show newly uploaded images in vue3 project with vite4 on production after build. I try every code I found on net but still no success. I try to show user profile image that is store in src/assets but if I have image in build is show, if upload new its not show. Here is my code how I take the image

```
const profileImg = new URL(
      `../assets/images/avatars/${currentUser.avatar}`,
      import.meta.url
    ).href;
```

After upload I get this in 'profileImage' "site-host/undefined"

I try to get images like is in documentation for vite 4 for dynamic images with this code

```
function getImageUrl(name) {
  return new URL(`./dir/${name}.png`, import.meta.url).href
}
```

But not working. Please any help

Comment: import.meta.url is from vite 4 ... I didn't set that variable in vue3 with vite 4 if you want to take env files and other proecs is use "import.meta", the  "process,env " not working any more

Comment: Really no one has problems with newly uploaded images after builds?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved the problem. I discovered that user avatars can't store in front-end applications (Vue). So I store the avatars in the nodejs server and send them to Vue in base64 format.